# GO : Parsing byte array of excel data using https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx library in GOLANG

Tags: arrays, excel, parsing, go

I want Parse byte array of  excel data using https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx library in GOLANG.
Actully i am getting data from the request(as byte array) to my GRPC server where I have to parse and process  it.

I checked library API but it accepts file name as parameter.

```
"github.com/tealeg/xlsx"

func main(){
xlsx.OpenFile("file.xslx")
}
```

Any idea how do I pass byte array directly and process the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.
Used 
     func OpenBinary(bs []byte) (*File, error)